# Java class initialization conundrum

Tags: java, inheritance, access-modifiers

I am using NetBeans' GUI Designer to create some `JDialog`s, which I then subclass from my own `EditorDialog` class.

Before I go further, consider this sample code:

```
class MyDialog extends EditorDialog {
    private Color someVariableThatTheGuiNeeds = new Color(0,50,100);

    public MyDialog() {
        super(true);
    }

    //<auto-generated>
    private void initComponents() { //note this is private!
        //...
    }
    //</auto-generated>
}

abstract class EditorDialog extends JDialog {
    public EditorDialog() {
        super(null,true);
    }
    public EditorDialog(boolean stuffNeedsDone) {
        super(null,true);
        //initComponents();
        doStuffAfterGuiInitialized();
    }
}
```

The problem is, I can't call `initComponents()` from my superclass, because it is private.

To get around this, I tried a workaround to the classes:

```
//in EditorDialog
public EditorDialog(boolean stuffNeedsDone) {
    super(null,true);
    workaround();
    doStuffAfterGuiInitialized();
}
protected abstract void workaround();

//in MyDialog
@Override
protected void workaround() {
    initComponents();
}
```

And, of course, this doesn't work, because `someVariableThatTheGuiNeeds` isn't initialized when `initComponents()` gets called because of the way the initializations happen:

- `new MyDialog()`

  - `super(this)`

    - `EditorDialog(boolean)` is called

      - `super(null,true)` is called, `JDialog` does stuff
      - `EditorDialog`'s instance variables are initialized
      - `workaround()`
      - `initComponents()`

        - `doSomethingWith(someVariableThatTheGuiNeeds)` -> **NullPointerException** because `someVariableThatTheGuiNeeds` isn't initialized yet
  - *NOW* `someVariableThatTheGuiNeeds` is initialized

Also, I cannot create a non-private abstract `initComponents()` in `EditorDialog`, because the visibility when overriding can only become more public.

So, how can I get around this problem, without making it too hackish?

(If you are unfamiliar with NetBeans, I **cannot** edit auto-generated code, and there is no option (that I could find) to change access modifiers on the `initComponents()` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your constructors shouldn't call non-`private` methods in any case. If you require initialization for your dialogs after they are created, you can create an `init()` method that should be called after the constructor is finished.

Note, the method name `doStuffAfterGuiInitialized()` indicates a bit of a misunderstanding.  The GUI, or even the instance, isnt fully initialized until after the constructor completes.

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem that is common in java.
Instanciation is not a friend of subclassing.

An indirect solution is used by many : call an init() method once the object is fully build.

This is often automated via a factory.
All injection frameworks (like Spring) do this routinely.